# trigger directive link on change on another element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like this

```
app.directive('ppTypeahead', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            // get data using ajax and fill typeahead options
        }
    }
});
```

The data to be fetched from server depends upon a dropdown selection. for example, `select` changes the items to be shown in the typeahead of the `input`.

```
<select
    ng-options="col as col.col_name for col in meta_data.cols track by col.col_id"
    ng-model="row.col">
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="row.value" pp-typeahead="{{row.col}}" />
```

How can I trigger a refresh of `input`'s typeahead on change of `select`?

Also, I am passing `{{row.col}}` as a value to the `directive`, is it correct? Or I should be doing something else to access that `model` from inside of the `directive`. Note that the `model` can't be just accessed like `scope.model.col`. It's an array, so I won't know which row I am on.

**Update:**

I see that doing a `$watch` inside the directive could be a solution. But I don't want to over-engineer it and implement it as a result of some action. `ng-change` of the `select` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the data like so:

```
app.directive('ppTypeahead', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            col: '=ppTypeahead'
        }
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            // get data using ajax and fill typeahead options
        }
    }
});
```

Then you could `scope.$watch('col', function(){/*...*/})` and call whatever function you need.

Comment: Thanks, any solution that don't require use of `$watch`?

Comment: That is the simplest way to connect these two scopes. You can use `ng-change` to call a function on the parent controller that broadcasts an event or something like that but it wouldn't be simpler.

Comment: Yes, I tried making a service and my directive would listen for the events. But as you said, its not simpler. I'll go with the `$watch`